# Create new loop dependent variable by iterating over rows

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am translating this piece of sas code into pandas. The sas code basically groups observations by a key. Within each group, it creates a new variable `A`, where `A[0] = B[0] / C[0] / .25`. Then for `i >= 1`, `A[i] = A[i - 1] * .85 + B[i] / C[i]`. `B` and `C` are other variables in the dataframe.

I don't think any `df.groupby().attribute` does this.

```
data data;
set data2;
by key1 key2;
retain A;
if first.key1 then A = (B / C) /(.25);
else A = A * .85 + B / C;
run;
```

Expected output for group g01

```
key1 B C A
g01  1 2 2       2     = 1 / 2 /.25
g01  2 1 3.7     3.7   = 2   * .85 + 2 / 1
g01  2 4 3.645   3.645 = 3.7 * .85 + 2 / 4
```

I have been thinking about getting the group keys first and loop over these group names. But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: please give your sample input and output , someone may be help you

Comment: you can check the apply function which you can pass with groupby, however we would need sample data and an output as @Kiran said to reproduce the issue and come up with any solution. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks!  I add the expected output. Can you guys please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works using [`pd.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), given that you have a DataFrame `df` containing the columns `B` and `C` that hold the values, as well as a column `key1` that holds the groups name:

```
g = None
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if g != r.key1:
        a = r.B / r.C / .25
    else:
        a = a * .85 + r.B / r.C
    df.loc[i, 'A'] = a
    g = r.key1
```

It is impossible to tackle this problem in a parallel fashion, because of the [loop dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_dependence_analysis), that is indicated by your use of `[i - 1]` and my caching of the variable `a` and `g`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Two questions:1. does this work by group? This program seems to iter over the entire dataframe. 2. instead of "if not a", do you mean "if a"? The calculation of a for the first one in each group should be different from the rest of the group

Comment: 1. Yes, it does now. I reread your question and adapted the answer. 2. The `if not a` was correct, as is the `!=` which checks for a group change. You might need to sort the dataframe by group first for this to work though.